# ArgumentException on Image.Dispose()

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making an album application with windows forms and I have a problem that I can't solve. First of all I have a form where I create a TableLayoutPanel. After that I create a method where I generate the same amount of picture boxes as the amount of the images in the directory which I have opened. The problem occurs when I am trying to dispose the image which I load in the picturebox because I need to free its memory. Here is the code of the method:

```
public void createPictureBoxes()
    {
        Image loadedImage;
        int imageCounter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCounter; i++)
            for(int p = 0; p < imagesTable.ColumnCount; p++)
            {
                PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
                pb.Width = imagesTable.GetColumnWidths()[p];
                pb.Height = imagesTable.GetRowHeights()[i];
                pb.Click += new EventHandler(enlargeThumbnail);
                try
                {
                    loadedImage = Image.FromFile(images[imageCounter++]);
                    pb.Image = loadedImage;
                    loadedImage.Dispose();
                    imagesTable.Controls.Add(pb);
                    loadedImage.Dispose();
                }
                catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
```

The program throws an ArgumentException on method Show() of the form telling me that the argument is not valid. Without the dispose method all works fine but if i try to load a large amount of images the program uses gigabytes of memory. I suppose that it is not right to dispose the image memory that way, but I can't come out with another idea. If someone could help I would be very grateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems: you're disposing twice, and further you won't be able to dispose of an image control so long as a parent control container is expected to use it. When the form is disposed then it will cause all controls to be disposed that are part of its container.

So, much less than trying to dispose twice, don't dispose at all (here, that is)!

Comment: Disposing the image twice actually isn't a problem, it's just unneccesary. You can call `Dispose` several times without harm.

Comment: @Guffa Well potentially yes, and maybe specifically with this type, but it's not guaranteed by implementation (is it even documented as recommended?) - I've even seen types expose an `IsDisposed` property and throw `InvalidOperationException` on subsequent calls to `Dispose`. Bad practice is still a problem, IMO. I would avoid it.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was certain that the problem is that the picturebox still uses the image when i am disposing it, but I should have asked to become more certain.

Comment: @GrantThomas: If you look at the documentation for the `Dispose` method, it's defined as an absolute must: *"If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one. The object must not throw an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times."*. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx

Comment: @Guffa Very well, I'm glad that's explicit on MSDN - maybe a 'no elephants' sign?

Answer (score 2):

You can't dispose the image while you are displaying it. If you do, the form can't display it.

The `PictureBox` doesn't make a copy of the `Image` instance when you assign it to the `Image` property. It keeps the instance, so you can't dispose it until you have removed the image from the picture box.

Comment: Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: @ByteBlast: Sorry, I thought that was obvious. Simply don't dispose the image.

Comment: Of course that's the solution to the exception but what about the memory issues? I'm interested in another perspective.

Comment: @ByteBlast: If you need to display images without keeping them in memory, then you have to implement your own control that loads images from file as needed. An `Image` object loaded using `FromFile` keeps the file open, so it's not supposed to load data until it is needed, but it's not guaranteed to release memory once the image is loaded.